# Fridge is warm, freezer is still coldish

Tags: refrigerator, freezer

I have a Whirlpool top-freezer (model wrt549szdm00). My freezer temp is at 15F, fridge is at 50. It's been this way for a couple days now. I took the freezer apart, and there was no ice on the coils. Ice maker still works, but I've turned it off.

Occasionally, there's a really loud thumping sound, like someone throwing a plastic toy at the inside of the fridge. It usually happens in a series of 3 or 4 times, once every 45-60 seconds, at random times throughout the day/night. I'm not sure what's making that noise; I turned off my ice maker and it still happened. Sometimes it's quieter than others, for example in one series of 3 thumps, the first two will be loud, and the last one quieter.

Could this be a damper/diffuser issue? Or something totally different?

Comment: If it was a damper or diffuser, I would expect one compartment to be warm and the other cold. They are both **much warmer than they should be**. 50 refrigerator is not safe. 15 freezer is safe but far from ideal. The big question is whether this is a thermostat problem or a functional problem (e.g., compressor).

Comment: If you can move your food to some other fridge and defrost this one for 24+ hours that might be diagnostic. I know that's inconvenient. But no ice on the coils does not eliminate the possibility of ice in ducts screwing things up...

Comment: @Ecnerwal: ... or an ice chest, which is my usual solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just an update for anyone looking:

I was able to fix this by **replacing the evaporator fan motor**. Has been working since November 2023, shortly after my original post.